# Regex find replace to add function parameter

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find and replace some function calls in py program. The idea is to add some boolean parameter to each call found on the project.
I looked for solutions on the internet 'cause I don't know regex science at all... It seems like a basic exercice for regex guys but still.

In my case I have this call in a lot of files :

```
myFunction("test")
```

My gooal is to find and replace this call into :

```
myFunction("test", false)
```

Could you help me write the regex ?

Comment: If I may suggest: I was not the downvoter (my opinion is that your question is, in essence, reasonable) but, on Stack Overflow, there exists a style that usually avoids downvotes. The style is not easy to master but, in the specific case of your question today, you might have presented the question as a practical example you were using to learn about regexes. Then, if you showed something you had tried, the question would have been even better received. I do not criticize, of course, but make a possible observation regarding someone else's unexplained vote, based on analogous past experience.

Comment: At your discretion, you can edit your question by clicking "edit" above. Don't worry. I get downvoted sometimes, too. Usually, there is something I can do, by editing, to improve my own question after a downvote, so it's all right.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
sed -re 's/(myFunction)[[:space:]]*\([[:space:]]*("test")[[:space:]]*\)/\1(\2, false)/' SOURCE_FILENAME
```

If you prefer to replace the existing source file with an updated one, then write `-i SOURCE_FILENAME` instead of `SOURCE_FILENAME`.

This works by defining a *pattern* to match the function call you would like to update:

- `myFunction` (obviously) matches the text `myFunction`;
- `[[:space:]]` matches any whitespace character, mainly spaces and tabs.
- `[[:space:]]*` matches zero or more whitespace characters.
- `\(` and `\)` match literal parenthesis in your program text;
- `(` and `)` are regex *metacharacters* that match nothing, but `("test")` matches `"test"` and *captures* the matched text for later use.

Note that this pattern captures two things using `(` and `)`. The `("test")` is the second of these.

Now let us examine the overall structure of the Sed command `'s/.../.../'`. The `s` means "substitute," so `'s/.../.../'` is Sed's *substitution* command.

Between the first and second slashes comes the pattern we have just discussed. Between the second and third slashes comes the replacement text Sed uses to replace the matched part of any line of your program text that matches the pattern. Within the replacement text, the `\1` and `\2` are *backreferences* that place the text earlier captured using `(` and `)`.

So, there it is. Not only have I helped you to write the regex but have shown you how the regex works so that, next time, you can write your own.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this:

```
import re

#Replace all white-space characters with the digit "9":

str = "The rain in Spain"
x = re.sub("\s", "9", str)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use this regex to match and capture

```
(myFunction\("test")(\))
```

then use the regex below to replace

```
$1, false$2
```

[image]